# What's the default superuser username/password for postgres after a new install?

Tags: postgresql, user-management

I have just installed postgres 8.4 on Ubuntu 9.10 and it has never asked me to create a superuser. Is there a default superuser and its password? If not, how do I create a new one?

Comment: Probably very relevant - ["I'm installing PostgreSQL and don't know the password for the postgres user"](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#I.27m_installing_PostgreSQL_on_Windows_or_OS_X_and_don.27t_know_the_password_for_the_postgres_user).

Answer (score 643, accepted):

**CAUTION** The answer about changing the UNIX password for "postgres" through "$ sudo passwd postgres" is not preferred, and can even be **DANGEROUS**!

This is why: By default, the UNIX account "postgres" is locked, which means it cannot be logged in using a password. If you use "sudo passwd postgres", the account is immediately unlocked. Worse, if you set the password to something weak, like "postgres", then you are exposed to a great security danger. For example, there are a number of bots out there trying the username/password combo "postgres/postgres" to log into your UNIX system.

What you should do is follow **Chris James**'s answer:

```
sudo -u postgres psql postgres

# \password postgres

Enter new password:
```

To explain it a little bit.  There are usually two default ways to login to PostgreSQL server:

1. By running the "psql" command as a UNIX user (so-called IDENT/PEER authentication), e.g.:  `sudo -u postgres psql`. Note that `sudo -u` does NOT unlock the UNIX user.
2. by TCP/IP connection using PostgreSQL's own managed username/password (so-called TCP authentication) (i.e., **NOT** the UNIX password).

So you *never* want to set the password for UNIX account "postgres".  Leave it locked as it is by default.

Of course things can change if you configure it differently from the default setting. For example, one could sync the PostgreSQL password with UNIX password and only allow local logins.  That would be beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: so, how do you lock user postgres back?

Comment: @ultrajohn - depends on distribution you use, but you can edit /etc/passwd and put * instead of the password

Comment: `/etc/shadow` is where the password is kept @lzap.

Comment: Right, you can either set /sbin/nologin in /etc/passwd or put * instead of the password in /etc/shadow.

Comment: passwd --lock postgres

Comment: This is not programmatic. It's not any more "secure" just because you have to manually type in the password...

Comment: if after login to postgres, it don't required password, you can set password by this command: "alter user postgres password 'apassword';"

Comment: Still the best answer, nigh ten years on.

Comment: It works with PostgreSQL 15.3-1 on Ubuntu 23.04 .

Comment: To lock the password for user postgres, use `passwd -l postgres`. This disables login for that user without changing the actual password. To unlock, use the `-u` option.

Answer (score 194):

Enter on the command line:

```
$ sudo -u postgres psql postgres
postgres=# \password postgres
```

You'll see:

```
Enter new password: 
Enter it again:
```

Comment: This is what's needed to use a tool like pgadminIII (when setting up a server profile) immediately after Postgres itself is installed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 70):

You manipulate postgres through the user `postgres`, as so:

```
# su - postgres
$ createdb mydb
$ psql -s mydb
# create user someuser password 'somepassword';
# GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE mydb TO someuser;
```

Comment: When I su to postgres, it's asking for a password. I don't recall inputting one before. Is there a way to reset that password for postgres?

Comment: @ThierryLam You must be root to `su` to the postgres user without entering a password. On most systems the Postgres Unix account is locked (no password will work), which means *only* root may `su` to that account.

Comment: Use `sudo` instead of `su`.

Comment: I had to run `sudo su - postgres` :\

Comment: @Jim Schubert: you can also run `sudo -u postgres`.

Comment: sudo -u postgres psql - works also so you can do it in one step.

Answer (score 25):

In Windows, do the following (IMPORTANT: Use a Windows **administrator** account):

1. After installation, open `<PostgreSQL PATH>\data\pg_hba.conf`.
2. Modify these two lines, and change "md5" to "trust":

   `host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5`

   `host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5`
3. Restart the PostgreSQL service (might not be necessary).
4. (Optional) Open a command prompt, and change code page to 1252:

   `cmd.exe /c chcp 1252`
5. Log in to PostgreSQL.
   Non password will be needed (notice the uppercase -U parameter):

   `psql -U postgres`
6. (Optional, recommended for security reasons) Change the `postgres` user's password:

   `\password postgres`

   and change "trust" back to "md5" in `pg_hba.conf`.

Answer (score 6):

If you are trying to access the PostgreSQL shell, you can type:

`psql -U postgres my_database`

Where `my_database` is your database name.